# type="number" react typescript false positive in onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got error in line 24

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)

using typescript for a react experiment.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState<string>(null);
  const [tel, setTel] = React.useState<number | undefined>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={name}
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        value={tel}
        type="number"
        placeholder="tel."
        onChange={e => setTel(e.target.value)} // here?
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-moore-wve1p

It doesn't happens with type="text" I've already specify the type, it's strange.

Comment: 1) All information relevant to the question should, to the extent it is possible, be included in the question itself. (_Supplementary_ links are welcome.) What is the error message? 2) What is the code _supposed_ to do? The code in your sandbox does not match the code in your question.

Comment: Edited my question, I missed that.

Comment: @MellisaLee take a look at the types you set in the useState, then take a look at the  initial values you have there :)

Comment: Ah! I see what you were referring to originally.

Comment: Probably looking for this `onChange={e => setTel(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))}`

Comment: yeah @Jacob parseInt worked. But why need the second params? I don't get why radix is needed here

Comment: Glad to help! Just keep in mind if you tell something what type it should be, make sure it is getting that type :)

Comment: @Jacob you said: "take a look at the types you set in the useState, then take a look at the initial values you have there" but how to debug that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203946/discussion-between-jacob-and-mellisa-lee).

Comment: You defined the types for the initial state. So that means it would need to look something like this

const [name, setName] = React.useState<string>('');
const [tel, setTel] = React.useState<number | undefined>(undefined);

The last bit is, since you said the error was a type error on the line for the setTel() input, I looked at the event which I assumed returned a string but I checked anyway and was correct. So all it needed to be done is parseInt so that it matched the defined type in the setState
hope that helps with the thinking process.

Comment: Oh the radix is defined because the linter prefers that in codesandbox and its not a terrible practice to be explicit anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments adding the parseInt() to change the `string` type number from the event into a number will match the type you set for that `useState`

I also changed the initial values of the `useState's` to match their defined types.

```js
  const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState<string>('');
  const [tel, setTel] = React.useState<number | undefined>(undefined);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={name}
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        value={tel}
        type="number"
        placeholder="tel."
        onChange={e => setTel(parseInt(e.target.value))}
// setTel('12312')<string>  => setTel(parseInt('12312'))<number>
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```